# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in D:\laragon\www\pos\src\session.php on line 6

Tags: php

I have a problem error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in D:\laragon\www\pos\src\session.php on line 6

and I can't find a solution to fix it. Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Session
{

    public function __construct(public string $username, public string $role)
    {
        
    }

}

class SessionManager
{

    public static string $SECRET_KEY = "xxxxx";

    public static function login(string $username, string $password): bool
    {
        if ($username == "edward" && $password == "edward") {

            $payload = [
                "username" => $username,
                "role" => "customer"
            ];

            $jwt = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($payload, SessionManager::$SECRET_KEY, 'HS256');
            setcookie("TRPS-SESSION", $jwt);

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function getCurrentSession(): Session
    {
        if($_COOKIE['TRPS-SESSION']){
            $jwt = $_COOKIE['X-PZN-SESSION'];
            try {
                $payload = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($jwt, SessionManager::$SECRET_KEY, ['HS256']);
                return new Session(username: $payload->username, role: $payload->role);
            }catch (Exception $exception){
                throw new Exception("User is not login");
            }
        }else{
            throw new Exception("User is not login");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the `public` qualifier on your constructor arguments `public function __construct(public string $username, public string $role)` should be `public function __construct(string $username, string $role)`

Comment: Arguments to a function don't have access modifiers.

Comment: [Constructor property promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion) requires php 8.0